# Optimize 2 nested for loops with GRanges

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, bioconductor, parallel-foreach

I'm trying to optimize 2 nested for loops with GRanges in them.

My original GRanges is:

```
annot_cnv

GRanges object with 1733140 ranges and 3 metadata columns:
seqnames                ranges strand |      GENEID                       SAMPLE Segment_Mean
   <Rle>             <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>                  <character>    <numeric>
    chr1   [3301765, 44149504]      + |       81569 TCGA-05-4433-01A-22D-1854-01       0.0889
    chr1   [3301765, 44149504]      + |      252995 TCGA-05-4433-01A-22D-1854-01       0.0889
    chr1   [3301765, 44149504]      + |      252995 TCGA-05-4433-01A-22D-1854-01       0.0889
    chr1   [3301765, 44149504]      + |      252995 TCGA-05-4433-01A-22D-1854-01       0.0889
    chr1   [3301765, 44149504]      + |      252995 TCGA-05-4433-01A-22D-1854-01       0.0889
```

And the 2 nested for loops are:

```
cnv_data <- data.frame()

for (i in unique(annot_cnv$SAMPLE)) 
{
 sample_data <- annot_cnv[annot_cnv$SAMPLE == i,]
 for (j in unique(sample_data$GENEID)) 
  {
   cnv_data[i,j] <- mean(sample_data$Segment_Mean[sample_data$GENEID == j])
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use the function foreach but I don't know how to use it keeping the sample name as rownames and the GENEID as colnames in the final data.frame.

Can someone help me optimize these loops to do them in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

The general strategy will be to make a GRangesList using `splitByList()`, and then calling `mean()`; it will calculate the mean of each element of the list. So along the lines of

```
grp = interaction(annot_cnv$GENE_ID, annot_cnv$SAMPLE)
grl = splitAsList(annot_cnv, grp)
mean(grl)
```

Better to ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the [Biocondunctor support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `for-loop`. One of many options available in `r` using `dplyr`package can be:

```
library(dplyr)

annot_cnv %>%
  group_by(SAMPLE, GENEID) %>%
  mutate(Avg = mean(Segment_Mean))
```

The `Avg` column created above will contains your desired result.